# Writing power function in Standard ML with a predefined compound function

Tags: sml, ml, mosml

Having trouble writing a power function inStandard Ml. Im trying to write a function called `exp` of type `int -> int -> int`.

The application `exp b e`, for non-negative `e`, should return `b^e`.

For example, `exp 3 2` should return 9. `exp` must be implemented with the function `compound` provided below. `exp` should not directly calls itself. Here is the `compound` function, it takes in a value `n`, a function, and a value `x`. All it does is it applies the function to the value x n number of times.

```
fun compound 0 f x = x 
  | compound n f x = compound (n-1) f (f x);
```

Im having trouble figuring out how to write this function without recursion, and with the restraint of having to use a function that only can use a function with one parameter. Anyone have any ideas of where to start with this?

This is what I have:

```
fun exp b 0 = 1  
  | exp b e = (compound e (fn x => x*x) b)
```

I know that this doesn't work, since if i put in 2^5 it will do: 
2*2, 4*4, 16*16 etc.

Comment: `compound` recursively calls itself... I edited the question to make it fit what you mean.

Comment: The function compound is allowed to be recursive, but the function exp is not allowed to be recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do this instead I believe

```
  fun exp 0 0 = 1
  | exp b 0 = 1
  | exp b e = (compound (e - 1) (fn x => b * x ) b);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are extremely close. Your definition of `exp` compounds `fn x => x*x` which (as you noticed) is not what you want, because it is repeatedly squaring the input. Instead, you want to do repeated *multiplication by the base*. That is, `fn x => b*x`.

Next, you can actually remove the special case of `e = 0` by relying upon the fact that `compound` "does the right thing" when asked to apply a function 0 times.

```
fun exp b e = compound e (fn x => b*x) 1
```

Comment: Would I send a tuple to compound in order to send it both the base and the value of x?

Comment: The base doesn't change from iteration to iteration, so no need! Just writing the function exactly as I did in the answer will be correct. For more information, you might be interested in reading about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: That makes sense such a small thing! Thank You!

Comment: No problem. I've also just edited the answer with a solution that eliminates the special case when `e = 0`, making the final code quite elegant.

Answer (score 0):

this may not be exactly 100% proper code.  I sort of just now read a bit of Standard ML documentation and took some code and reworked it for your example but the general idea is the same for most programming languages.

```
fun foo (num, power) =
let
  val counter = ref power
  val total = 1
in
  while !counter > 0 do (
    total := !total * num
    counter := !counter - 1
  )
end;
```

To be more clear with some pseudo-code:

```
input x, pow
total = 1
loop from 1 to pow
  total = total * x
end loop
return total
```

This doesn't handle negative exponents but it should get you started.

It basically is a simple algorithm of what exponents truly are: repeated multiplication.

```
2^4 = 1*2*2*2*2 //The 1 is implicit
2^0 = 1
```

Comment: The OP requires that one use the `compound` function he/she listed above.

Comment: The main problem i'm running into is how to keep the original base number b and use that for the multiplication. I feel like I have to use multiple calls to compound, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I was thinking the same.  Basically break down the multiplication to addition.  2^4 = 2*2*2*2 = 2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2.  3^5 = 3*3*3*3*3 = 3+3...+3

Comment: Unfortunately I have to step out so I can't keep working on this but hopefully it gives you an idea